# Android: optimal way to find shortest distance between Point and Rect?

Tags: android, math

Seems like there should be some convenient way to do this?

I couldn't find one, so I threw together the below algorithm.  Is it memory/computationally optimal?

Thanks:

Edit: Original algorithm was stupidly wrong, maybe this is better?

```
public static float minDistance(RectF rect, PointF point)
{
    if(rect.contains(point.x, point.y))
    {
        //North line 
        float distance = point.y - rect.top;

        //East line
        distance = Math.min(distance, point.x - rect.left);

        //South line
        distance = Math.min(distance, rect.bottom - point.y);

        //West line
        distance = Math.min(distance, rect.right - point.x);

        return distance;
    }
    else
    {
        float minX, minY;

        if (point.x < rect.left) 
        {
            minX = rect.left;
        } 
        else if (point.x > rect.right) 
        {
            minX = rect.right;
        } 
        else 
        {
            minX = point.x;
        }

        if (point.y < rect.top) 
        {
            minY = rect.top;
        } 
        else if (point.y > rect.bottom) 
        {
            minY = rect.bottom;
        } 
        else 
        {
            minY = point.y;
        }

        float vectorX = point.x - minX;
        float vectorY = point.y - minY;

        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((vectorX * vectorX) + (vectorY * vectorY)); 

        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, the answer you have chosen gives you the distance to the closest corner of the rect, not the distance to the perimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the closest point and then get the distance to that.
Off the top of my head:

```
    float closestX, closestY;

    if(point.x >= x1 && point.x <= x2 && point.y >= y1 && point.y <= y2)
    {
         float bestDistance = point.y - y1;
         bestDistance = Math.min(distance, y2 - point.y);
         bestDistance = Math.min(distance, point.x - x1);
         bestDistance = Math.min(distance, x2 - point.x);

         return bestDistance;
    }

    if (point.x < x1) {
        closestX = x1;
    } else if (point.x > x2) {
        closestX = x2;
    } else {
        closestX = point.x;
    }

    if (point.y < x1) {
        closestY = y1;
    } else if (point.y > y2) {
        closestY = y2;
    } else {
        closestY = point.y;
    }

    float vectorY = point.x - closestX;
    float vectorY = point.Y - closestY;

    float distance = sqrtf((vectorX * vectorX) + (vectorY * vectorY));
```

Comment: I think this fails if inside the Rect?  For a point inside the Rect, this will always give distance of 0?

Comment: It only gives you the distance to the closest corner of the rectangle. What if it is on the line between two corners? The distance should be zero.

Comment: In retrospect, mine was stupidly wrong as well.  Because it doesn't work for vertical lines (gives infinite slope), which a rectangle has two of.

Comment: @ab11: Yes, if the point is inside the Rect, the distance is 0. I would assume that to be expected behavior in a "distance from point to rect" test, unless the point is to get the distance between the point and a perimeter, not the rect as a shape.

Comment: @EboMike. Yes, distance from perimeter is what I meant, I should've clarified.

Comment: @gamernb: Distance to closest edge, not corner. I'm not sure what you wanted if the point is on or inside the rect - I assumed 0, which is what this code will do.

Comment: @EboMike.  So, I should probably add a if(rect.contains(point)) conditional.  Use your alogrithm for the case where it does not contain the point, and implement something else for the other case?

Comment: Updated the code. Actually, I may have to rethink it, I was jumping the gun without thinking. Give me a second.

Comment: @ab11: Yep, your new code should do the trick! Kinda like my latest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

One optimization is to not use the square root until the end. If you just compare distance squared and then return the sqrt of the smallest distance squared, you only have to do one sqrt.

Edit: Here is a good example of the distance from a point to a line segment (edge of the rect). You can use it, and modify it so that it returns the distance squared instead. Then compare them all and return the sqrt of the min distance squared.

[Distance Between Point and Segment](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=194400)

Answer (score 1):

The natural approach is to consider the eight areas outside the square, four corners and four laterals. This gives the shortest distance possible to the border of the square. If the point is inside the square (perhaps a button) then distance is zero, but if a distance is required is the shortest straight to the four borders.